# How to present myself to other cultures on cover letters

Tags: work-environment, presentation

I'm a Brasilian developer and I'm currently looking for reallocation to another country. For that, I need a cover letter for my resume, but Brasilians tend to be playful and not that formal even on cover letters - *don't get me wrong, we can treat serious situations seriously when needed* -.

My question is: when presenting myself to an European (for example) employer through my cover letter, is it better for me to be all serious or to make some respectful jokes and talk about stuff that doesn't really matter for the job (Example, talking about how I am deeply inserted to the culture on England because my 3 favourite pop culture things are from there - Doctor Who, Harry Potter & Sherlock Holmes-)

Comment: What country in Europe? I doubt these jokes are a good idea, though.

Comment: The one I want the most is actually England, but the netherlands, Denmark, Finland, any other from the UK is also great. and really any other country that employs me haha

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although questions about interactions taking place in a workplace are on topic here, what to include in a cv and what not isn't exactly a good fit for Interpersonal skills. I think this is better fit for [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com), according to their [Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell my question is not what to put in a cv, but the way i should put it. Still, i get why the question can be interpreted both ways

Comment: @CarlosMion So are you in fact asking how to format a CV for a specific recipient? I'm afraid that isn't on topic either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State facts factually.

While I personally never would, you may include hobbies and personal interests as a very short side note (unless relevant for the job), but keep the tone mostly neutral. If you want to explain why you are looking specifically in England for a job, something like

> ... Aside from my general interest in your company, I do like the opportunity to work in England, as I like/am interested in the (local music) culture. Therefore, I would certainly be willing to relocate.

would do (to give you an example of fitting tone, feel free to formulate better/differently etc).

You should however try to find out whether your humour matches with the local company culture when you're at the interview stage. It typically doesn't make sense to work at a totally strict company department when you prefer to have a relaxed funny atmosphere at work.

There might be the rare exception to go for a more loosened style when the offer description already is very "special", i.e. humorous itself or claiming to look for creative individuals. But then it's a hit or miss game - in general, try to be as formal as the job offering.